# Accessing elements in a xaml defined style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have followed the DiagramDesigner example on Codeproject for learning how to use Adorners in WPF as it fits quite a few of my needs relatively closely.

I have adapted the implementation a little, and also added my own adorner, for controlling the opacity of a control via a slider (slider on the adorner).

Following the same methods as the author, I placed the slider and other feature in a xaml style definition file as below. I am just now struggling A) to figure out how to access the slider at any level, B) how best to start hooking this up with an underlying Viewmodel that will be used for various settings (on adorners).

```
<Style x:Key="OpacityAdorner" TargetType="{x:Type adorners:OpacityChrome}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type adorners:OpacityChrome}">
                <Grid>
                    <Slider x:Name="OpacitySlider" Style="{StaticResource OpacityControl}" ToolTip="Alter the opacity of the image to overlay with other images" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="OpacitySliderEnable" Style="{StaticResource OpacityIcon}" ToolTip="Alter the visual opacity of the image" Visibility="Visible"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The codeproject example is here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Use something like the following snippet to get the slider from the applied template.

```
var slider = opacityAdorner.Template.FindName("OpacitySlider", opacityAdorner) as Slider;
```

there are cases where the template has not yet been applied, in that case you need to preceed the previous call with the following:

```
opacityAdorner.ApplyTemplate();
```

B) The best approach for hooking up with the view model (in my opinion) is to expose the required properties as **dependency properties** on the `OpacityChrome` adorner. You then use normal `Binding` to hook up the new properties to the view-model, and `TemplateBinding` to hook them up to the template elements.

Comment: Thanks for this. It has helped. I still had a bit of pain with implementing it though. I wanted to get the slider when the adorner was constructed in order to hook in events to attach to dependency properties. However ApplyTemplate() still didn't apply the template at this stage, and the template was still null. I've had to hack in something that does work. Is there a method I can override in the adorner instead so I will know the template has been applied? (OnApplyTemplate did not worith either)

Comment: OnInitialized() works actually. Don't really like this method of having to hook up controls/events in the Adorner manually in OnInitialized but there doesn't seem to be much of a way around it that I can see

Comment: And I still needed to ApplyTemplate() before trying Template.FindName or there would be a race condition as to whether Template was null by the time the code was reached in OnInitialized